# Does Microsoft Word spellcheck require the Internet?

Tags: microsoft-word

Does Word check spelling/grammar on Microsoft's servers or on my computer?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting from the network and seeing if it still works?

Comment: noit is done with the help of a software installed in your program . this has nothing to do with your Interne

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it doesn't.

When you install Microsoft Office, it will install a dictionary of your main language - however, this isn't much more than a list of words. You can also install additional languages later. You do not need an internet connection for this.

In addition, in any Office program, you can hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on any word to perform research on it - this includes translating, dictionary (with full definition) and thesaurus. All of these research features require an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks @surfasb for that, Guess I wasn't clear... done a little more.

Answer (score 3):

(this information is current as of Word 2003)

All spellchecking is local. The spellcheck data is stored in the file `CUSTOM.DIC` in
`C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\Proof`. (WinXP path)

You can add, edit, and remove dictionaries used in Word; go to
`Tools -> Options...`, select the tab `Spelling & Grammar` and click on `Custom Dictionaries...`.
Here you can check what the file is on your system and it's location

Answer (score 2):

It checks spelling on your own computer (tested with Microsoft Office 2010 on a VM)